# Scringo Help (Freezes / Sigbart)

Tags: facebook, freeze, scringo

I have Scringo all set up in my application. However after the user logs into facebook and returns to the app the app freezes and my log shows this error.

```
2012-07-24 10:25:56.724 BlackOps2[3558:907] -[__NSDictionaryM stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd510
2012-07-24 10:25:56.728 BlackOps2[3558:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd510'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3544356b 0x3572397f 0x354474fb 0x35445c0d 0x35397e68 0x2ba0b 0x24ead 0x30b49 0x42fc7 0x2242f 0x1c4f1 0x1c8c3 0x35fec5b5 0x35f3d991 0x35f3d8ad 0x318a6acf 0x318a61bb 0x318ce323 0x3538a2e1 0x318ce783 0x31832c65 0x35414143 0x354139a9 0x354126ef 0x35390c1d 0x35390aa9 0x3825433b 0x364fa535 0x2731 0x26f0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(gdb)
```

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is because your FB app includes some advanced setting that tells Facebook to use a response format that should be activated by default only in Oct, 2012 and your Scringo version still doesn't support it.

To make it work you should either:
1) Update to the latest Scringo version
or 
2) Go to your FB app settings (where you registered your FB app), and choose the Advanced Settings. There, you'll see a Migration section. Make sure the following field is DISABLED:
October 2012 Breaking Changes  (this will work until 3, Oct 2012)